# Equivalent of AMD's require.toUrl for ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, requirejs, amd

I'm currently in the process of converting a JavaScript library from AMD modules to ES6 modules.

Some of these modules use [**`require.toUrl`**](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/require#requiretourlstring-) for converting a path from a path relative to the module to a path relative to the base. How can I achieve the same effect in my ES6 modules?

Note that I'm looking for a solution that works not just in webpack, but in any loader or bundler that supports ES6 modules, as well as in browsers that support ES6 modules natively!

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to remove `requirejs` from your project... if so, `require.toURL` is a `requirejs` feature

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn : `require.toUrl` is supported by both RequireJs & Dojo 1.7+. Not sure about other loaders like SystemJs. Either way, removing RequireJs (or the Dojo loader) as a dependency is indeed part of the scope here. As is improving compatibility with Webpack & other modern bundlers.

Comment: I think you will need to write your own `twoUrl` function or use a dependency since it isn't in native es6

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn : I was afraid of that. That sucks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently, but there's the [`import.meta` proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-meta) that would allow things like [`import.meta.resolveURL()`](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3871) or [`import.meta.resolve()`](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps/issues/79) methods.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, it looks like no single loader or bundler supports it yet. How silly to come up with a module standard and leave such an important feature for a later state. It makes refactoring legacy code so much more difficult than it should be...